# how I could search with wildcards in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have this piece of text which repeats more times just changing number before "Done" word because I want to replace with "," character?

```
COMMIT;
RAISERROR (N'[dbo].[LIB_table]: Insert Batch: 113.....Done!', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LIB_table]([ID], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [Col6])
VALUES
```

thanks in advance to all!! 
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't support wildcard matching, but it supports far more powerful regular expressions for search and replace. From your question I can't really tell, what exactly you want to replace, could you please give an example?

Comment: I want to replace the whole text in evidence at main post which repeats many times, except the number 113 which changes every time increasingly, with character "," because I have a loooong INSERT INTO in same table breaked with those texts and I wanted to unify all lines to add at the end ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  col1 = VALUES(col1),...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I found it by myself using this RegEx expression:

```
COMMIT([\s\S]*?)LIB_IpToCountry([\s\S]*?)VALUES
```

Thanks anyway Sebastian